# Входные параметры для java процедуры

Tags: java, linux

Допустима ли следующая сигнатура у процедуры при ее объявлении

```
public void PreparationOfInputParameters(ArrayList<String> therms, ArrayList<Integer> idoffiles, ArrayList<Integer> countthermsinfiles)
```

в плане параметров? Также хотел спросить допустима ли передача одноименных значений при вызове функции, т.е. строка вида

```
PreparationOfInputParameters(therms, idoffiles, countthermsinfiles);
```

?

Answer (score 3):

1. Да, допустима.
2. Да, допустима.
3. Почему бы вам самому не проверять подобные вещи? Напишите функцию с такой сигнатурой, передайте ей такие параметры, запустите программу, убедитесь, что она работает.

Comment: @fori1ton да я понимаю, что не прав (можно самому проверить), но сроки ограничены, после 21.05.13 я задавать такие вопросы не буду. Прошу прощения за некорректный вопрос, но обстоятельства вынуждают. Спасибо большое.

Comment: @ivan89 написать вопрос быстрее чем запустить тест ?

Comment: @ivan89: если такие вопросы возникают, я бы посоветовал вам (после 21.05.13) просто почитать хорошую книгу по Java. На ХК были вопросы по поводу книг с многочисленными ответами.

Comment: А что случится 21 мая?

Answer (score 3):

0) Так нельзя

1) Да

2) Да

Пояснения к п. 0 - [согласно соглашению об именах функций/методов](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367): имя функции/метода обычно начинается с глагола/действия с прописной буквы, при этом каждое слово в имени метода должно начинаться с заглавной.

**P.S.** `PreparationOfInputParameters()` - такое именование характерно для C# прогеров, но не Java :)

> Methods should be verbs, in mixed case
> with the first letter lowercase, with
> the first letter of each internal word
> capitalized.

То есть метод ваш должен называться: `preparationOfInputParameters()`

Comment: +1 за стандарт-нацизм. :-)

Comment: @Barmaley: не обижайте C#, действия должны быть глаголами и в нём, и везде. (Я бы использовал `prepareInputParameters` в Java и то же с большой буквы в C#.)

Comment: а переменные из плюсов с _value начинать или в андроиде с mValue, кто будет?

Comment: А вот это как раз стандарт-нацизм :) Prepare/PreparationOf разница невелика. Смысл поста был в обучении @ivan89 правилам Java - и как показывают его посты он реально учится. А ваши комментарии действительно сродни [граммар-наци](http://lurkmore.to/Grammar_nazi) - без обид.

Comment: @Barmaley: для меня XYZ-наци — комплимент. :-)